# How can I add an animation to my custom view object with onClickListener?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view fcard which defined with xml.
fcards will be listed in my activity. I want to set an onClickListener to imageView which defined in fcard's.
I have already write my adapter extended from ArrayAdapter. The adapter's getView method given below. If convertView defines as a final object, it cannot be inflated. other way should be define as final for use in imageView's onClickListener and startingAnimation.
how can I  accomplish this problem? 
I am new on android ,thanks

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) cfcard).getLayoutInflater();
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_facility_card, null,
                false);
        holder.tvSender = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.fcardTvSender);
        holder.tvDate = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.fcardTvDate);
        holder.tvPostTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.fcardTvPostTitle);
        holder.tvPostDetail = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.fcardTvPostDetail);
        holder.ivFcardBtn = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.fcardButton);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tvSender.setText(fcards.get(position).getTvSenderStr());
    holder.tvSender.setText("sender");
    holder.tvDate.setText("date");
    holder.tvPostTitle.setText(fcards.get(position).getTvPostTitleStr());
    holder.tvPostDetail.setText("detail");

    final Animation anim;
    holder.ivFcardBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                    android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
    });
    convertView.startAnimation(anim);
    return convertView;

}
```

**Edit**
I can fix the problem with using implements View.OnClickListener on myAdapter and setOnClickListener(this) to clickable objects. I guess it will help someone. There is my new code below.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) cfcard).getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_facility_card, null,
                false);
        holder.tvPostTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.fcardTvPostTitle);
        holder.ivFcardBtn = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.fcardButton);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tvPostTitle.setText(fcards.get(position).getTvPostTitleStr());
    holder.ivFcardBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.tvPostTitle.setOnClickListener(this);

    return convertView;

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // ViewHolder holder; is defined global at myAdapter class
    int viewId = v.getId();
    if (viewId == holder.ivFcardBtn.getId()) {
    //ivFcardBtn clicked
        LinearLayout parentpnl = (LinearLayout) v.getParent().getParent();
        ObjectAnimator myanimator= (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater
                .loadAnimator(getContext(), R.animator.fcardanimator);
        myanimator.setTarget(parentpnl);
        myanimator.setDuration(3000);
        myanimator.start();

    } else if (viewId == holder.tvPostTitle.getId()) {


        //tvPostTitle clicked. 

    }

}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here? you want animation when the  list of images are laid out?

Comment: let your adapter implement View.OnClickListener and call setOnClickListener(this)

Comment: @Biu, I want to start animation for my custom view(converView) when the imageView (ivFcard) clicked. If I call startAnimation in onClick method, convertView should be final. If convertView was be final, it cannot be inflate in this getView function. So my problem is "how should I use startAnimation function?". Thanks

Comment: @pskink yes it's right but how can I handle my customView's items, I try to in onClick(View v) method if(v==holder.ivFcardBtn) but this condition returns false ( v.equals(holder.ivFcardBtn) returns false too). How should I do? Thanks

Comment: Use setTag/getTag for a View you are setting the lidtaner and pass whatever you want as a tag

Comment: @pskink I have already use setTag but when onclick running getTag don't give the clicked object. I can fix the problem using "if (v.getId() == holder.ivFcardBtn.getId())" statement at onClick method. Thank you for your help